# Postgresql could not determine data type of parameter $1 using php pdo

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I want to print string value inside query. I defined variable in array. 
On the below main query that is working when I execute query I get result.

```
$query = "SELECT count, mahkoy_kod , mahkoy_adi, ilce_id, st_x(st_transform(st_centroid(t2.geom),4326)) as lng,st_y(st_transform(st_centroid(t2.geom),4326)) as lat from 
(SELECT count(*),t1.knt_f_mahkoy_id FROM a.s_all t1                                             
where st_intersects(t1.geom,st_transform(ST_GeomFromText( format('POLYGON((%s %s, %s %s, %s %s, %s %s, 
%s %s))', 29.743849487304715, 41.24992343698962, 28.481108398437527, 41.24992343698962, 
28.481108398437527, 40.749326052646055, 29.743849487304715, 40.749326052646055, 
29.743849487304715, 41.24992343698962 ), 4326),500000)) 
group by knt_f_mahkoy_id ) t1
join analiz.k_spt_dis_mah_koy t2 on t1.knt_f_mahkoy_id = t2.mahkoy_kod 
where  count > 100";
```

When I use php pdo I get error is

> Could not determine data type of parameter $1
>   Blockquote

It is php code. Here database class used to run query. When I print data with var_dump I get error. How can I solve this problem?

```
$query = "SELECT count, mahkoy_kod , mahkoy_adi, ilce_id, st_x(st_transform(st_centroid(t2.geom),4326)) as lng,st_y(st_transform(st_centroid(t2.geom),4326)) as lat from 
(
  SELECT count(*),t1.knt_f_mahkoy_id FROM a.s_all t1                                             
  where st_intersects(t1.geom,st_transform(ST_GeomFromText( format('POLYGON((%s %s, %s %s, %s %s, %s %s, %s %s))', 
 :long_high, :lat_high, :long_low, :lat_high, :long_low, :lat_low, :long_high, :lat_low, :long_high, :lat_high ), 4326),500000)) 
  group by knt_f_mahkoy_id 
) t1
  join analiz.k_spt_dis_mah_koy t2 on t1.knt_f_mahkoy_id = t2.mahkoy_kod  where  count > 100";

$data = Database::query($query, array("long_high"=>$long_high, "lat_high"=>$lat_high, "long_low"=>$long_low, "lat_low"=>$lat_low));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not much into postgres but suppose you can do it another way

```
$polygon = sprintf('POLYGON((%s %s, %s %s, %s %s, %s %s, %s %s))', 
$long_high, $lat_high, $long_low, $lat_high, $long_low, $lat_low, $long_high, $lat_low, $long_high, $lat_high);

$query = "SELECT count, mahkoy_kod , mahkoy_adi, ilce_id, st_x(st_transform(st_centroid(t2.geom),4326)) as lng,st_y(st_transform(st_centroid(t2.geom),4326)) as lat from 
(
  SELECT count(*),t1.knt_f_mahkoy_id FROM a.s_all t1                                             
  where st_intersects(t1.geom,st_transform(ST_GeomFromText( ?, 4326),500000)) 
  group by knt_f_mahkoy_id 
) t1
  join analiz.k_spt_dis_mah_koy t2 on t1.knt_f_mahkoy_id = t2.mahkoy_kod  where  count > 100";

$data = Database::query($query, array($polygon));
```

the idea here is to provide a POLYGON function as a complete string literal. It is both safe and compatible.